# Innosetup - are user CreateInputOptionPage "wizard" pages shown when /silent, etc is specified?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, wizard

InnoSetup setup executables have command line options to permit unattended or batch file operation - i.e. it is possible to have command-line parameters like /SILENT, /VERYSILENT,  such that no "wizard" pages are displayed.

If I add my own wizard pages using `CreateInputOptionPage` will these still display, i.e. do I need to add further command-line options to suppress these (and provide default responses) as well?

(Yes, I *could* try it myself, but the answer will likely be useful to others, and there might be further issues I haven't thought of)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run with /SILENT or /VERYSILENT  dialogs that you create such as `CreateInputOptionPage` will not be shown.      `InitializeWizard()` is still called and the forms are still created.

So any values you read from these Wizard Pages will be the default values.

You can have specific behavior in Pascal Script when silent by using the `WizardSilent()` function.

You can also check the parameters sent to the install in Pascal Script using the
`ParamCount` and `ParamStr` functions or you can get the whole string using `GetCmdTail`.